# (Java) How can I use minecraft original commands in my plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

What I use : Intellij IDEA, Java, Minecraft mod - Paper plugin, Gradle to build

What I want to Ask : What I have to download,import,etc.

For example : /time set day , /op (someone) , /kill (someone) , /ban (someone)

You can criticize for my question

Comment: There is no question. Please [edit] to more explain, add details what you tried etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute it as console, you can use this:

```
String command = "time set day";
Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), command);
```

if you want to execute it as a player, u should replace Bukkit.getConsoleSender() with a player object.